# Counting Amount of subsets from a set

Tags: combinations

Let set S = {a1, a2, a3, ..., a12}, where all 12 elements are distinct. We wish to form subsets, each of which contains one or more of the elements of set S (including the possibility of using all the elements of S). The only restriction is that the subscript of each element in a specific set must be an integer multiple of the smallest subscript in that set. For example, {a2, a4, a6} is an acceptable set, as is {a6}. How many such sets can be formed?

I was thinking of dividing the problem in cases, one for 3 elements, and then 4 and 5 and so on. This would take way too long so can I have help doing it a faster way?

Comment: you can probably use permutation

Answer (score 1):

The constraint relates to the smallest subscript, so it makes more sense to branch on that, rather than branching on the size of the subset. You want to branch on something which simplifies the constraint, so instead of *"each subscript is a multiple of the smallest subscript"* you have e.g. *"each subscript is a multiple of 3"*. Then within each branch it's much easier to count.

You only want to count non-empty subsets, so every subset has a smallest subscript:

- If the subset contains a<sub>1</sub>, then each of the 11 remaining elements can be freely chosen as either present or not present. There are 2<sup>11</sup> such subsets.
- If the smallest subscript is a<sub>2</sub>, then there are 5 possible other elements a<sub>4</sub>, a<sub>6</sub>, a<sub>8</sub>, a<sub>10</sub>, a<sub>12</sub>, each of which can be freely chosen as either present or not present. There are 2<sup>5</sup> such subsets.
- If the smallest subscript is a<sub>3</sub>, then there are 3 possible other elements a<sub>6</sub>, a<sub>9</sub>, a<sub>12</sub>. There are 2<sup>3</sup> such subsets.
- If the smallest subscript is a<sub>4</sub>, then there are 2 possible other elements a<sub>8</sub>, a<sub>12</sub>. There are 2<sup>2</sup> such subsets.
- If the smallest subscript is a<sub>5</sub> or a<sub>6</sub>, then there is one possible other element (a<sub>10</sub> or a<sub>12</sub> respectively). There are 2 subsets for a<sub>5</sub> and 2 for a<sub>6</sub>.
- Otherwise, the smallest subscript is a<sub>7</sub>, a<sub>8</sub>, a<sub>9</sub>, a<sub>10</sub>, a<sub>11</sub>, or a<sub>12</sub>, and the subset cannot contain any other elements due to the restriction. There is one subset in each case.

The total is therefore 2<sup>11</sup> + 2<sup>5</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 2,102.

---

Generalising this argument, if there are *n* elements in the original set, then the total number of subsets satisfying this constraint is:

[image: formula]